# Delaying part of circuitry

Tags: esp8266, delay, home-automation

I am trying to design a board controlling the powering up of an Esp8266 with the following features

- low consumption
- power on at fixed interval (kind of a heartbeat)
- power on, when an edge is detected on a specific input say IN1
- monitor the state of IN1 with the ESP

The way I designed the board so far uses a TPL5110 for the low consumption side and schedule, together with an edge detecting circuit connected to the manual trigger of the TPL.

The edge detection circuit consists in two sets  of capacitors and resistors that will  charge (resp discharge) when IN1 changes state. The caps discharge to a npn transistor that will feed the manual trigger of the TPL.

This setup works rather satisfyingly... as long as the edge detection is connected to the manual trigger after being charged. 
The reason for that is that at startup the TPL reads the timing configuration on the same pas the manual trigger (basically reads a resistor value by flowing g some current there). The rising edge triggers at startup and interferes with the TPL startup setting.

I was looking for a simple  a way to delay switching on the edge detecting side but I couldn't find out how.. any thoughts or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

For completeness, the project is to build a low consumption WiFi door monitor, with a magnetic switch connected to IN1.
[image]

Comment: Post a schematic please. Much better than written text describing the circuit.

Comment: Too much confusing hand waving.  Closing without schematic or system diagram.

Comment: How long a delay.  The old hack is to use some RC/ diode low pass in front of a Schmitt trigger.

Comment: Hi ! Here goes the schematics.

Comment: The delay should be around roughly 20-50 microseconds

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVujjC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This might work better depending on your actual timing diagram specs.

- 20~30us dual edge +ve pulse on switch toggle. Can be debounced better than shown.

Comment: Hi ! 
Thanks for the suggestion, I ran a simulation (didn't have time yet to test on a breadboard) and did the math, this seems to do the job !

My only concern is related to power consumption, as the whole point using a TPL is to reduce power consumption.. I might be looking for low power Xor gates..